# New CPU, MOBO & RAM - Lagging?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

So I just bought myself a new CPU, MOBO and RAM.

GPU: GTX 1660 SUPER
CPU: i7-10700k

I bought the I7-10700k with a z490-p motherboard.

After installing all the components and booting the pc, i went into some counter strike where no problem occurred. In fact there is not a single problem when i'm just using the computer. BUT! as soon as I want to stream on twitch with Streamlabsobs, my streaming software starts to lag a whole crazy amount. The game isn't lagging just everything on the stream.

Anyone with an idea or solution to my problem?

- Alex/Shaaxy

Comment: Run something local and see how the machine runs.  Then do a speed test (speedtest.net) and if your Internet is performing well. Make sure you have a network card that is performing well.

Comment: Since this would primarily be all GPU; What GPU you can [edit] your question

Comment: Ramhound I added the GPU in my qusetion.

Comment: John, my interenet is performing as usual, so very fine, and so is the network card. Everything was working perfect before II upgraded the CPU, MOBO and RAM

Comment: Did you re-install the OS? If not, what hardware did you use before?

Comment: I did not re-install the OS, didn't know that was needed for upgrading. Used a i7-4770s before